# how i can insert unkown number of element to array in O(0)

Tags: java, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

Question from job interview

Given function which receives as parameters an array and an int number, that function has to insert the given number to all the places in the array in O(0) time.

Comment: What is `o`, or is it zero ? If the former, specify what is `o`.

Comment: O(o) time would suggest no time at all. Which can't be done. I assume they/you meant O(1)?

Comment: Big O notation. I think, Ask for lesser time by O(o)

Comment: This will be O(n) with n being the size of the array. You can make it O(1) by specifying a limit to the size of the array and adding dummy operations when n is small.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, any code?

Comment: If o is a zero, then replace (by reference) the given array with an empty array (Yes maybe it is O(1) instead of O(0), it depends on your religion). It satisfies the given criteria. Absolutely no sense, but it is a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what they mean by `O(o)` but the nearest you can get is actually `O(n)`.

```
private void filArrayWith(int[] a, int f) {
    Arrays.fill(a,f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @OldCurmudgeon,

> Not certain what they mean by O(o) but the nearest you can get is actually O(n).

The function `Arrays.fill(int[] a, int val)` itself uses a plain for loop to assign the elements. So both solutions would be good in my opinion.
Below is the source code for the Arrays.fill method:

```
    /**
     * Assigns the specified int value to each element of the specified array
     * of ints.
     *
     * @param a the array to be filled
     * @param val the value to be stored in all elements of the array
     */
    public static void fill(int[] a, int val) {
        for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
            a[i] = val;
    }
```